# Prefix "redirect:" not able to resolve the view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was following the application example in the book - [Spring Recipes](http://www.apress.com/9781590599792), Section 8-10. And I am stuck in an issue.
I'll try to keep it short.

I've *Reservation* bean containing following fields:

```
String courtName, Date date, int hour, Player player, SportType sportType
```

*Player* bean contains just two fields - `name`, and `age`.

*SportType* is an *enum*:

```
public enum SportType {
    TENNIS("Tennis"), 
    SOCCER("Soccer");
    // Constructor, Getter
}
```

---

Now, I've a view - *reservationForm.jsp*, with corresponding controller - *ReservationFormController*.

The controller has the following annotations:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reservationForm")
@SessionAttributes("reservation")
```

Also, it has some methods, relevant out of them are:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(
          @RequestParam(required = false, value="username") String username,
          @RequestParam(required = true, value="age") int age,
                                                       Model model) {
    System.out.println("Setting Up Form");
    Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
    reservation.setPlayer(new Player(username, age));
    model.addAttribute("reservation", reservation);
    return "reservationForm";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(Model model, 
                       @ModelAttribute("reservation") Reservation reservation,
                       BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    
    reservationValidator.validate(reservation, result);
    
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("reservation", reservation);
        return "reservationForm";
    } else {
        reservationService.make(reservation);
        status.setComplete();   // Expires the session
        return "redirect:successfulReservation";
    }
}

@RequestMapping("successfulReservation")
public String reservationSuccess() {
    System.out.println("Called");
    return "reservationSuccess";
}
```

Now, when I deploy the application, and access the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/springmvc/reservationForm?age=21
```

The form is displayed from *reservationForm.jsp*. And after I hit submit button in that form, `submitForm()` method will be called.

The problem is, in that method, if validation succeeds, the return statement in `else` block:

```
return "redirect:successfulReservation"
```

is not working. It's showing an *HTTP Status-404*.

The url shown in the browser after I submit the form is:

```
http://localhost:8080/springmvc/successfulReservation?sportTypes=TENNIS&sportTypes=SOCCER
```

I don't understand how those 2 request attributes came in the query string.

When I tested whether the method handler- `reservationSuccess()` corresponding to *successfulReservation* is called or not, I saw that it's not being called. Due to which, the view is not being resolved.

Also, in the Eclipse console, it's showing a warning:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvc/successfulReservation] in DispatcherServlet with name 'court'
```

I can't understand what might be the problem.
I've added - `<context:component-scan>` in the configuration file.

This is the view resolver I've configured:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Also, it seems like, examples in that book are not complete. They haven't defined the `reservationSuccess()` method for *redirected* url. That I've added on my own.

Can someone help me out here, what's going wrong?

I've tried to compact as much relevant information as I can here. If you want some more information, do ask. I'll add.

Comment: @BheshGurung. Thanks. That works :) But isn't there any way to keep the url without `reservationForm`. When I moved that method in a different controller with `/successfulReservation` request mapping, it worked with `/successfulReservation` only. Isn't there any wy, keeping the method in the same conroller?

Comment: @BheshGurung. Anyways, you can add it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: *Isn't there any wy, keeping the method in the same conroller?* - Not sure about that :). Posted the comment as answer.

Comment: @BheshGurung. Thanks :) May be I'll get to know as I proceed further with the topic. Will add it here, if there happens to be some way.

Comment: @Downvoter. It seems like you are looking around for my questions, and already downvoted 3 of them. I'll not say not to do it, but at least add a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should redirect to `/reservationForm/successfulReservation`.

Since the method is within the controller, and controller also has request-mapping, may be the method's request-mapping is not independent of that of the controller.